# How do I restrict jQuery selectable multiple to select maximum upto 5 range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code is allowing me to select all items, but I need to select only 5 items max.How can I do that?

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
  selected: function(event, ui) {        
    if (!$(ui.selected).hasClass('ui-selected selected-flag')) {
      $(ui.selected).addClass('ui-selected selected-flag');
    } else {
      $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-selected selected-flag");
    }        
  }    
});
```

Comment: the above one is allowing me to select all items but i need to select only 5 items max please do guide me...!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can select the elements with those classes and check if the `length` of that selector is already `5`, then perform no action.

Also note that your current `if` statement can be reduced to just call `toggleClass()`.

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
  selected: function(event, ui) {  
    if ($('.ui-selected.selected-flag').length < 5) {
      $(ui.selected).toggleClass('ui-selected selected-flag');
    }
  }    
});
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped